# Odd Behavior When Using ON_CALL before EXPECT_CALL with Gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

Has anyone ever seen seen odd behavior in gmock when following an ON_CALL statement with an EXPECT_CALL statement? For me, the EXPECT_CALL statement in the following code doesn't work (it doesn't actually enforce the Times part):

```
ON_CALL(myMockObject, myMockMethod()).WillByDefault(Return("hello mock")));
EXPECT_CALL(myMockObject, myMockMethod()).Times(99999);
myMockObject.myMockMethod();
```

*Other solutions that I've tried:*

Overriding the myMockMethod from the super class and have it simply return a string literal. The problem with this is that I can't determine how many times it's been called later on.

Skipping the ON_CALL part in favor of something like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(myMockObject, myMockMethod())
    .Times(1)
    .WillRepeatedly(Return("hello mock"));
```

This results in a compilation error.

Also of note, the string literal I'm using in this example is custom in reality and something that gmock won't be able to come up with a default for (such as bool).

Comment: With `.Times(1)` have you tried `WillOnce(Return("hello mock"))`?

Answer (score 2):

You have some other error in your original code which is not being mentioned in your question.  The code provided in the question behaves as you expected if you construct a minimal self-contained example.

For example, the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

using ::testing::Return;

struct MyClass {
  virtual ~MyClass() {}
  virtual std::string myMockMethod() = 0;
};

struct MyMockClass : MyClass {
  MOCK_METHOD0(myMockMethod, std::string());
};

TEST(MyClass, Fails) {
  MyMockClass myMockObject;
  ON_CALL(myMockObject, myMockMethod()).WillByDefault(Return("hello mock"));
  EXPECT_CALL(myMockObject, myMockMethod()).Times(99999);
  myMockObject.myMockMethod();
}

TEST(MyClass, Passes) {
  MyMockClass myMockObject;
  EXPECT_CALL(myMockObject, myMockMethod()).Times(1).WillRepeatedly(Return("hello mock"));
  myMockObject.myMockMethod();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

produces the following (expected) output:

> ```
> [==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
> [----------] Global test environment set-up.
> [==========] 2 tests from MyClass
> [ RUN      ] MyClass.Fails
> ..\src\main.cc(18): error: Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(myMockObject, myMockMethod())...
>          Expected: to be called 99999 times
>            Actual: called once - unsatisfied and active
> [  FAILED  ] MyClass.Fails (0 ms)
> [ RUN      ] MyClass.Passes
> [       OK ] MyClass.Passes (0 ms)
> [----------] 2 tests from MyClass (2 ms total)
>
> [----------] Global test environment tear-down
> [==========] 2 tests from 1 test case ran. (2 ms total)
> [  PASSED  ] 1 test.
> [  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
> [  FAILED  ] MyClass.Fails
>
>  1 FAILED TEST
> ```

If you want your mock object to be held in a test fixture, you can do:

```
class MyClassTest : public testing::Test {
 protected:
  MyMockClass myMockObject_;
};

TEST_F(MyClassTest, Fails) {
  ON_CALL(myMockObject_, myMockMethod()).WillByDefault(Return("hello mock"));
  EXPECT_CALL(myMockObject_, myMockMethod()).Times(99999);
  myMockObject_.myMockMethod();
}
```

Comment: Does my mock object need to be instantiated inside of each test method? I know that this is good form (and self-contained), but I usually try to create common objects in some kind of fixture.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(&myMockObject);
```

This did the trick. I'm still not sure how expectations are managed behind the scenes, but this got me working.

Any further explanation of this would be greatly appreciated, though.